# Is JMS Queue an implementation of Java Util Queues? What are classes in Java package using Java Util Queue implementations?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, jms

Is JMS Queue an implementation of Java Util Queues?

I am looking for some classes where Java Quees are used internally. Can anyone please enlighten on same?

Answer (score 1):

JMS queues implement `javax.jms.Queue` with provider specific implementations.

The simplest example of `java.util.Queue` (and `Deque`) is `LinkedList`.

```
Queue<String> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
Deque<String> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide more classes which are using Queue inherently.

Comment: @fatherazrael why? What are you looking for?

Comment: Theory. Got question in interview; how you used queue practically. As i have not used so i need to explain scenarios from java package itself. :(

Comment: @fatherazrael I can't think of too many places where those are used internally. `BlockingQueue` has more use in the concurrent classes.

Comment: Ok. Let me check then one or provider specific implementation, he might have used Queue only. Will mark it as answer. Thanks for direction